# Small C/C++ library for GLSL image processing?

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing, glsl

For an upcoming project I'm looking for a small cross-platform library that will easily let me apply multiple GLSL fragment shaders to images. Just basic 2D image processing, really. I'm experienced in C++ and GLSL shader writing but haven't done much work in OpenGL.

All actual image processing will be done using GLSL shaders, so I don't need a huge library with image processing functions, model and image file loading and so on.

I just want the library to handle the OpenGL context, dealing with setting up FBOs and loading/applying the given shaders. I do not want to display the resulting image in a window, so a simple setup for windowless rendering is desirable.

I have looked at the common OpenGL frameworks and had some success with SFML, but unfortunately SFML only supports textures with 8-bit color -- I need full 32-bit float precision for this task. Probably frameworks like Cinder could handle my requirements, but it just seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do.

So... any ideas for small libraries that will make it easy to apply GLSL shaders to 2D images in an FBO?

Comment: well, I think you just want basic openGL. Though, I am not too sure how to go about getting a non displayed rendering context, which I think is what you are really after. SDL is a cross platform GUI library that supports openGL rendering and does not abstract the openGL it self, you just use your normal openGL  functions

Comment: Unfortunately I probably don't have the time to dive deep into OpenGL for this project, which is why I was hoping a small library could help me out.

I'm surprised that it's so hard to find a library for this. It would seem like a pretty straightforward thing for a library to handle: "Hi library, here's a 32-bit image and some parameters. Go process it for me using your GLSL magic. Return to me the processed image".

Comment: It's not exactly diving deep into openGL, especially as you are alrady using shaders.

Comment: [http://glip-lib.sourceforge.net/](http://glip-lib.sourceforge.net/) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SFML for creating context and loading files, and then manipulate on them in memory using OpenGL functions. They are really simple and if you are really experienced in shaders you will have no trouble learning them.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use some of the Enlightenment Foundation Libraries (EFL) for that.  I've not played with their OpenGL stuff, but I plan to.  I have used some of them for an embedded project.  You could use the EFL evas library, with it's OpenGL engine, and just render to a software buffer.